# UPNP Media server?

Tags: 11.04, mediaserver, upnp, xbox-360

I am looking for a simple UPNP media server software.

This does not have to be a full system.

All I want is for my xbox 360 to be able to play music off my laptop.

I want it to pick up all media in my ~/Music directory.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm getting the same problems as Hailwood, but with 'minidlna'. Playing songs on the xbox gives twenty to fifty seconds of sound, then silence till the last couple seconds, where the last bits of song are played. These issues do not appear when playing on other clients, like vlc. Currently searching some solution to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rygel](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/rygel) might be what you are after.  It implements the UPnP AV Media Server interface with the DLNA extensions.  There is some code in there to support the Xbox 360's quirks (Xboxes won't talk to UPnP servers that don't look enough like Windows Media Player), so is worth a shot.

The default configuration should pick up music in your `~/Music` folder through the media export plugin, but you can configure this through the `Rygel Preferences` control panel.

If your music is not in a format the Xbox supports, Rygel is also capable of transcoding it to either raw PCM data or MP3 (assuming you have the correct GStreamer plugins installed).

Comment: Hmm, so How do set it to start and run automatically?

Comment: Hmm, It is running perfect... Except I keep getting gaps in the middle of my songs?

Comment: Selecting the `Enable UPnP/DLNA` option in the preferences dialog should add Rygel to your startup applications.  I'm not sure about the gaps in the song playback.  Does it occur for all file types, or just some of them?

Comment: All of em... its annoying, you get about 30 seconds of play, the silence for the rest of the song, except the last second or so which is the song...